# Issues with leaflet fitbounds

Tags: leaflet

I am tracking device with gps coordinates. I need to fitbounds map from starting location of device to recently received gps location in realtime. I tried using map.fitbounds(); but unable to achieve it. 
Can somebody help on this?

```
 for(markersArray){
 var southWest = L.latLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng); // starting marker
 var northEast = L.latLng(parseFloat(preciseLat), parseFloat(preciseLng));// current marker
 var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast);
 map.fitBounds(bounds);}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **map.fitBounds** function expect a **LatLngBounds** parameter as stated in the [leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds), you can put the starting point marker and the current point marker in the same layer group and then use this code :

```
map.fitBounds(myMarkersGroup.getBounds().pad(0.5));
```

I've created a JSFiddle with a full example :  https://jsfiddle.net/ro8nL7s1/

Comment: I simply maintained array say markers of gps location. And using L.marker() method to add it to map. So don't have any featureGroup, I am new to leaflet, Can you please elaborate how do i make markerGroup?

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle with a full example, please accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: what is the pad(0.5) do?

Comment: pad(0.5) is a half percent padding that ensures no marker icons are cut-off from view.

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem with following. Main issue was with maxZoom parameter. I set it so that map is prevented to auto zoom

```
 map.fitBounds([
                          [preciseLat, preciseLng],
                          [markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng]
                        ],{maxZoom : 13});
```